# refering someone as 君

Tags: word-choice

I always thought that 君 is only used by males to refer to females as 2nd person. Usages:

1.male -> female , 君、あなた (君 is used only in romantic situations)

2.female -> male , あなた (Not possible to say 君 at all. In fact, even あなた sounds weird since it really means "husband")

3.male -> male , 君、あなた

4.female -> female , 君、あなた

Question is, for #1, is the assumption right that if 君 is used, it signals that the male is trying to be flirty with the female? For #2, is the assunption right that females will never use 君 to refer to a guy? And あなた also seems weird so to speak since it really means "husband". So how does a female refer to a male apart from by the name

Comment: "So how does a female refer to a male apart from by the name" You're aware that's by far the most common and most natural way to refer to people, right? Even if someone "couldn't" use あなた for some contrived reason, they wouldn't be troubled by it.

Comment: Well aware. Take a situation where you are talking to someone you don't know. In that case, if you somehow need to refer to that person, you can't very well use that person name isn't it, because well, you don;t know the name

Comment: So, you're supposing that if a woman couldn't use a man's name, using あなた would be weird because you're saying it "means" husband?

Comment: @Leebo Is this really something worth being so passively aggressive about? I am not sure, which is why I am asking the question?Why would I ask a question I know the answer to?

Comment: @Newbie, I assure you this is not passive-aggressive, it's just plain Leebo style.

Comment: Also, to add something constructive, in my experience, when talking to someone you don't know the name, I think you can call them by their title or position. For example 店長さん (store manager). Also, it isn't necessary to use a pronoun at all in many cases, so you can safely refer to someone just by context, without saying their name, a title, a pronoun or anything like that. For example, お元気ですか。That is, just fallback to pronouns if there is absolutely no way to disambiguate by context who you are referring to (which is usually not the case).

Comment: @Newbie, it looks like your post contains 3 different questions (1: "Is the assumption right that if 君 is used, it signals that the male is trying to be flirty with the female?", 2: "Is the assunption right that females will never use 君 to refer to a guy?", and 3: "How does a female refer to a male apart from by the name?"). You may get better, more accurate answers if you post them as separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler than I think you are putting it. First of all, if you are speaking Japanese the best advice is to learn your partners name and use that. If it is a case where you don't know their name, あなた is a fine option as it is the polite way to address someone else. 君 is often used when your are talking to someone who is below you in some way, and it has a familiar sound to it. Although in practice you don't hear these all that often, most people refer to each other by name unless they are fairly close.